# Secondary monitor not working

Tags: display

I've had this issue both with Elementary OS and Xubuntu which both run Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Every time I would boot up either Elementary or Xubuntu I would be left with my primary monitor working and my secondary monitor would not be working.

Occasionally after tinkering with the display settings I would get it to appear only for it to disappear after I turn my secondary monitor on and off or do a reboot.

A bug report has already been posted for it on launchpad: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1313539

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fortunately I seem to have ran into a solution for Elementary OS and felt it would be best to share it.

Open up the application launcher and search for Additional Drivers and select 'Using Video driver for the AMD graphics accelerators from fglrx-updates (proprietary)'.

After I rebooted my system, both monitors have been working and I've tested to secondary monitor to ensure it works even after you turn it on and off.

I hope this helps people who have similar issues to what I had.